# How do you run the Intern's self tests with SauceConnect?

Tags: intern

I am having a challenge running the self tests for the Intern.

I have modified the configuration of `intern/tests/selftest.intern` to point at my local host and I am running the following command line:

```
node runner config=intern/tests/selftest.intern
```

I connect to SauceLabs and the tests start, but all of them fail after about 120 seconds.  Looking at the output, once the tests are bootstrapped, I see that the initial pages load, but it attempts to fetch the following URL:

```
http://[myhost]:9000/intern-selftest/tests/all.js
```

To which a `404` is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running the self tests, there are two points to keep in mind:

1. There should theoretically be two copies of Intern when self testing: one that is *being* tested, and one that is "known" to be good, used to actually *do* the testing. The idea is that we are testing a new version of Intern with a known good version of itself.
2. The copy of Intern that is *being* tested should be named `intern-selftest`. [Check out what happens](http://d.pr/i/qW4r) on TravisCI when the self tests run, specifically noting two separate clones of Intern and the `mv intern intern-selftest` on line 40.